# Angular+gsap3 animation not working when clicked upon

Tags: angular, animation, gsap

app.component.html

```
<div #animate class="main">

    <div id="go" (click)="click()" class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

app.component .ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { gsap, Back, Bounce, Elastic } from 'gsap'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {


  ngOnInit() {
    this.animation();
    
  }


  click(): void {
    gsap.to(".box1", 3, { x: 200,background:"red", ease: Elastic.easeOut, paused: true })
    
  }

  animation() {
    gsap.to(".main .box", 3, { x: 200, stagger: 0.3, ease: Bounce.easeOut })
  }

}
```

When box1 is clicked the animation is not working, the other animations are working fine.Even i checked the console the click() is working and it shows the animations but the effect is not taking place

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me. Every time that the click() function is ran it is overriding the previous click function. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I tried this`document.getElementById("go").onclick = () => tween.play();` click function because the previous click() was not showing any result. I am trying to get he animation inside the Click() trying to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the

> paused: true

and when clicked upon the animation started working thanks to anyone who tried for the above

```
    gsap.to(".box1", 3, { x: 200,background:"red", ease: Elastic.easeOut }) }
```

this code works...

Comment: If you have resolved your own issue accept your answer to close the question! @Pirate80000006